# Database is taking forever to join the HA Group on SQl Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, high-availability, alwayson

We have 2 nodes in our environment and due to a failover that was caused by network connectivity issue, our databases weren't synchronizing on our secondary node. I tried resuming/starting data movement and that didn't help. I have tried several things and no help.

The last attempt, I was joining one database using Join Only via Wizard to see what error message I get. After 10 minutes "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The wait operation timed out."

I contacted out network team and they said its nothing on their end. Can someone help me to give me a list of things I should look for as to why the databases doesn't want to join the HA group any more. I want to see if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an issue with your lsn .

My advise ?

```
1st - Remove database from AG.
2nr - Remove database from secondary node (Is in recovery)
3rd - Add database to availability group.
```

---

After that, try to find why the failover happened.

How many interfaces you have ? You have a dedicated sync network ?
You have a Quorum disk ?

Hope this helps.